# What's the algorithm to verify user password?

Tags: password

I've the need to export user and hashed password from tbl_user to a new custom developed CMS.

> I'm not here to ask how to reverse the password !

I'd like only to know the steps, given a plain password, to create the SAME IDENTICAL password used by wordpress (4.7)

Is this possible? Is the algorithm available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Be aware that this is pluggable in WP so first of all check that you're site is using the default implementation.

Then have a look at [`wp_hash_password` and `wp_check_password` in `pluggable.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dd6da701b286579819cd6aa518aa2d7018efd759/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2002-L2088) and the [`PasswordHash` class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dd6da701b286579819cd6aa518aa2d7018efd759/wp-includes/class-phpass.php). There you should find what you are looking for.